# What is an alternative hitch for the Re~Cycled bike trailer?

Tags: trailer

What is an alternative trailer hitch for the Re~Cycled bike trailer?  This is the webpage of the trailer http://re-cycle.org/sites/re-cycle.org/files/Trailer.pdf

The reason I don't like it is because it tends to spring open and closed. Maybe use a ball and rod like this?
[image: ball socket like some trailers use]

Comment: Check instructables.com and search for bike trailers. There are many different ideas used to connect utility trailers.

Comment: I have a web page full of trailer building links, some of them might be useful to you:
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~armb/cycling/trailer.html

Comment: @josh the re-cycle web page PDF is gone.  Do you have any other images of the Before ?

Comment: @Criggie Every now and again I go through my trailer site replacing dead links with archive ones where possible. In this case,
https://web.archive.org/web/20130514025630/http://www.re-cycle.org/trailer/
(Though chasing the pdf version through re-directs will still take a few clicks.
It used a pipe bending spring as a flexible element.)

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer would be to find a trailer that you like that sells the hitch as a spare part, and use that.
For example https://carryfreedom.com/shop/hitches/